# Symbol not found for architecture arm64 ¿cual es el error en el codigo?

Tags: c++

os cuento, estoy haciendo un programa de ejemplo para ver mi nivel pero tengo un problema con openSSL, cuando lo uso me mete este error

> ====================[ Build | BankOfBlorcartComandLine | Debug ]================
> "/Users/borja/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/213.7172.20/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake" --build /Users/borja/CLionProjects/BankOfBlorcartComandLine/cmake-build-debug --target BankOfBlorcartComandLine
> [1/1] Linking CXX executable BankOfBlorcartComandLine
> FAILED: BankOfBlorcartComandLine
> : && /usr/bin/g++ -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/BankOfBlorcartComandLine.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/BankOfBlorcartComandLine.dir/Person.cpp.o CMakeFiles/BankOfBlorcartComandLine.dir/fecha.cpp.o -o BankOfBlorcartComandLine   && :
> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "_SHA512", referenced from:
> Person::Person(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits, std::__1::allocator >, Fecha) in Person.cpp.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

en cuanto al codigo que lo causa es el siguiente:

```
//
// Created by Borja on 21/3/22.
//
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include "Person.h"



Person::Person(std::string exName, std::string exLastname, Fecha exBirthday): name(exName),lastname(exLastname),
birthday(exBirthday){
    std::string *nombreCompleto = new std::string;
    *nombreCompleto = name + ' ' + lastname;
    std::cout << *nombreCompleto;
    unsigned char *mayonesa;
    mayonesa = SHA512((unsigned char*)&nombreCompleto,SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH,(unsigned char*) &mayonesa);
    std::cout << mayonesa;
}
```

Su .h es el siguiente (es una clase)

```
//
// Created by Borja on 21/3/22.
//

#ifndef BANKOFBLORCARTCOMANDLINE_PERSON_H
#define BANKOFBLORCARTCOMANDLINE_PERSON_H
#include <iostream>
#include "fecha.h"
#include <openssl/sha.h>
class Person {
public:
    Person(std::string exName, std::string exLastname, Fecha exBirthday);
    char identificacion[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string lastname;
    Fecha birthday;

};


#endif //BANKOFBLORCARTCOMANDLINE_PERSON_H
```

El main esta vacio (solo crea un objeto de la clase)
a la clase le falta mucho trabajo pero basicamente no puedo avanzar sin el hash asi que no se que hacer, llevo horas mirando que pasa y no encuentro nada, muchas gracias al que me ayude de antemano :D
PD: uso MacOS y mi pc es un air del 2020, no se si eso tiene algo que ver (no deberia, c++ es un lenguanje compilado)

Comment: OpenSSL tiene directivas para generar código válido en diferentes arquitecturas. Da la impresión que la versión de openSSL que estás usando no dispone de una configuración válida para ARM64. Si estás usando una versión antigua, podrías probar a descargarte la última versión de openSSL. En caso contrario creo que te va a tocar editar los archivos de la librería a mano para que funcione bajo ARM64

Answer (score 0):

Es un error "común" que se presenta (en el [foro de Apple](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/691111) también lo preguntaron).

Se arregla cambiando a *Paquete* en la configuración de compilación de tipo Mach-O.

Se tienen que agregar algunos marcos basados ​​en errores de símbolos faltantes que aparecen después de cambiar a *Bundle*.

Comment: ¡Hola! Las respuestas que son sólo un enlace se consideran de baja calidad porque, en el momento que el foro de Apple cambie el SEO y el enlace se rompa, la respuesta ya no le sirve a nadie. Por favor, considera [edit] tu respuesta y añadir los puntos principales de la solución. :)

Comment: Hola, creo que hay un error de comunicación, el usuario del foro habla de unity y C# (ademas de no usar libreria) en cambio yo uso C++ en Clion y estoy usando la libreria OpenSSL